# Windows Home Server 2011 and SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, remote-desktop, windows-home-server

I am running a home server with Windows Home Server 2011 and have set up Remote Web Access and Remote Desktop. I also have a valid SSL certificate from PositiveSSL which is set up on IIS. But whenever I connect with Remote Desktop or Remote Web Access, I get an error saying that the certificate isn't valid. So, how would I configure it so that the valid certificate is used?

Comment: Probably, you get this message due to server/domain name mismatch because that name isn't contained as a Subject Alternative Name in your SSL certificate. Try to reach a test page that resides to your SBS Server from the public internet and see if the message keeps showing. It will probably not as 3rd party issuers are known to public internet so it should be fine. If that works, contact your issuer and ask him to add the said name as a SAN.

Comment: tried accessing from a different network, same problem. there are self-signed certificates stored in IIS as well, and Home Server set up a different domain with Windows Live, as my registrar wasn't supported

Comment: Sorry, I have missed you somewhere between. I am just trying to figure out what you want to do and what's actually the issue. The existence of other self-signed certificates should not bother you, you should only bother for the certificate that is bind to that you are trying to access. Maybe the certificate warning during RDP logon contains the remote computer's hostname?

Comment: No, there's nothing about the remote host. Only the server's name is displayed. It seems to default to the included self-signed certificate, while there is another one that should work.

Comment: Then this one should help:http://serverfault.com/questions/566503/using-ca-certificate-for-remote-desktop-connection